# Вывод на страницу благодарности php вводимых данных из формы

Tags: php, javascript, html, form, label

Только у меня установлена отправка формы методом POST на сторонний сайт, а я хочу чтобы вводимые данные потом отображались людям для проверки введенной ими информации

```html
  
  <form class="m1-form" id="post_me" action="send.php" method="POST">
  <input class="field" type="text" name="fio" placeholder="Введите имя" />
  <input class="field" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Введите телефон" />
  <input type="hidden" name="additional" value="discount" />
  <button class="button-m" type="submit">Оформить заказ</button>
</form>
```

Comment: можно сделать с помощью ajax

Answer (score 0):

Добавил это в файл send.php на который происходил переход, но убрал отображение вводимых данных поля additional, т.к мне не нужно их выводить.

```html
      <?php
$fio = $_POST['fio'];

$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$additional = $_POST['additional'];

echo Имя:. $fio."<br />". Телефон:. $phone."<br />"; 
?>
```